# Autenticação com Facebook e Google no Firebase - Android Studio

Tags: android, facebook, login, autenticação, firebase

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo Android, com Android Studio, utilizando o Firebase inicialmente para a autenticação dos usuários.

O código está bastante extenso, por isso não o copiarei aqui, mas está disponível no [Github](https://github.com/renatasarmet/android-start-master/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/codelab/friendlychat/SignInActivity.java).

Já foi implementado o login com o Google, o usuário loga, vai para a tela inicial onde escolhe uma sala e, ao entrar na sala, aparece uma janela de chat onde pode mandar mensagens, inclusive já com foto e nome de perfil do Google.

Estou implementando agora o login com o Facebook de acordo com os tutoriais do [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login?hl=pt-br) e do [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android), já segui todos os passos de configuração em developers.facebook.com, como id do aplicativo, key hash etc, além da criação do botão de login com o Facebook.

O login está praticamente funcional, o usuário entra com sua conta pela janela padrão do Facebook, porém ao finalizar o login, o aplicativo volta para a tela inicial. Ou seja, pega as informações mas não vai para a activity seguinte (a MainActivity, onde estão as salas).

Eu e os outros desenvolvedores do app somos estudantes e iniciantes em programação Android, então acredito que seja algo simples mas não estamos conseguindo arrumar isso. Por sermos iniciantes também peço que se alguém responder, por favor explique em qual arquivo seria a modificação, o tutorial do Facebook é meio vago quanto a isso. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: O arquivo não tem o código de acesso com o Facebook. Cadê?

Comment: Veja esse video [Login Facebook com Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YO6Xx5glLPE) tenho certeza de que irá conseguir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Esse metodo eh chamado no onClick do botao do face

```
private void loginFacebookResult() {     
buttonFacebook.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            handlerFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
}  
private void handlerFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken accessToken) {

    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken.getToken());
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            showProgressDialog();

            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.w("Facebook Message:", "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Erro de Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Usuario user = new Usuario();
                user.setId(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                user.setNome(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());
                user.setEmail(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
```

user.setUrl(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl().toString());
                    user.saveBD();

```
                Intent intentMain = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, (sua classe destino).class);
                startActivity(intentMain);
            }

            hideProgressDialog();
        }
    });
}
```